# Cómo eliminar componentes de tipo string para "dibujar" una pirámide en C++?

Tags: c++, string, while, print, imprimir

Estoy diseñando un programa el cual pueda imprimir una pirámide según la altura de la misma, hasta ahora he hecho lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>


int main() {

 int contador = 4; // Es la altura de la pirámide, por dar un ejemplo
 string m = "";  //Es lo que está conformado la pirámide
 string espacio = " "; // Son los espacios para que se vea como una pirámide

 while(contador>0){
   espacio = espacio + " ";
   cout<<espacio;
   m = m + "**"; // Estos son sus "ladrillos"
   cout<<m<<endl;
   contador--;
 } 
 return 0;
}
```

Pero este programa lo que hace es imprimir los * desacomodados, generando esto:

```
  **
   ****
    ******
     ********
```

Y lo que me gustaría es que imprimiera de la siguiente manera:

```
   **
  ****
 ******
********
```

Estaba pensando en crear una estructura de control repetitiva para que creara una cadena de espacios de cantidad " " veces la altura - 1, y lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
  int contadorAuxiliar = contador;
  string espacioAuxiliar ="";

  while(contadorAuxiliar>1){
    espacioAuxiliar = espacioAuxiliar + " ";
    contadorAuxiliar --;
  }
  cout<<espacioAuxiliar<<"Aquí se detiene"<<endl;
```

Imprimiendo lo siguiente:

```
   Aquí se detiene //Noten que tiene 3 espacios, la misma cantidad de la altura menos 1
```

Pero sigo con el mismo problema, cómo pueda hacer para que esa línea de espacio se vaya reduciendo uno en uno hasta la base?, porque en el código (y mis capacidades actuales) sólo sé cómo aumentar el número de carácteres, y no eliminarlos.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como apunte, lo que tú llamas pirámide a mi me parece más un Zigurat.
[image]

Dejado de lado la nomenclatura arquitectónica Mesopotámica, podemos ver que tu estructura tiene una cúspide de dos caracteres y en cada piso que baja crece dos caracteres más:

> ```
>    **    | 2 caracteres
>   ****   | 4 caracteres
>  ******  | 6 caracteres
> ******** | 8 caracteres
> ```

Por otro lado, el espaciado antes de cada piso crece en uno desde la base hasta la cúspide:

> ```
>    **    | 3 espacios
>   ****   | 2 espacios
>  ******  | 1 espacio
> ******** | 0 espacios
> ```

Dado que sabemos la altura de antemano, este bucle nos muestra los caracteres de cada piso y los espacios de cada piso:

```
for (int piso = pisos, espacios = pisos - 1, caracteres = 2;
    piso > 0;
    --piso, --espacios, caracteres += 2)
{
    std::cout
        << "El piso " << piso
        << " tendra " << espacios
        << " espacios y " << caracteres
        << " caracteres\n";
}
```

Sabemos que la clase [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) dispone de un constructor al que le puedes pasar una cantidad y un carácter, dando como resultado una cadena con ese carácter repetido tantas veces como la cantidad proveída. Por lo tanto, este código generará tu Zigurat:

```
for (int piso = pisos, espacios = pisos - 1, caracteres = 2;
    piso > 0;
    --piso, --espacios, caracteres += 2)
{
    std::cout
        << std::string( espacios, ' ' )
        << std::string( caracteres, '*' )
        << '\n';
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9BCsMgEEXXeoqBLpK0EdrSVZLmJN2IsUFIVNRAoeTsdrSEUChuZr7vyVdYy8TE9RjjQWkxLYOEThkfnORzT6nSAWaudFnRNyXCaB/kyzpIuVXeeLjDraWUPI2DcksxzJc1SG@5UBn74gwuNQjuuAjSyZRfW0pItno4p5mxtNXA2Gb/GCdUKkqwDvFhaBphloAz6TrIO3ZXeixhlws81T9kfxWh4w4VD11gkxX/5WRYnE7F1hg/)</kbd>.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, tanto del código como la aclaración arquitectónica xd, realmente en estos casos el for viene siendo mejor manejarlo que el while

Comment: Como regla general, el bucle `for` se usa para casos en que se conoce el número de iteraciones mientras que el `while` se suele escoger cuando no se sabe cuántas iteraciones serán necesarias.

Answer (score 2):

Se puede lograr la pirámide con 3 pequeños cambios en tu código del principio:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>


int main() {

    int contador = 4;
    string m = "";  //Primero, inicializar la variable en blanco, no con 1 espacio
    string espacio = "";

    while(contador>0){
       /*En cada iteración, reseteo la cantidad de espacios
        pues voy a añadir los que necesite de cada vez*/
        espacio = "";
        /*Aquí en vez de añadir un espacio de cada vez, añado espacios igual a contador-1
        así me aseguro de que cada vez añado uno menos (que es lo que necesita la pirámide)*/
        for(int i=0;i< contador-1;i++){
           espacio = espacio + " ";
        }
        cout<<espacio;
        m = m + "**";
        cout<<m<<endl;
        contador--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Como ves, en vez de "eliminar espacios" lo que hago es resetear la variable entre cada iteración para no tener que eliminar nada, solo añadir menos cada vez.

**Edito para añadir ejemplo de cómo eliminar del final de un string**:

```
int main()
{
    string str = "Hola que tal";
    str = str.substr(0, str.size()-8);//Elimino los últimos 8 caracteres
    cout<<str;//Esto imprimirá "Hola" ya que borré " que tal"
}
```

Comment: Realmente se ve muy bueno, no lo había pensado así (no sé si fuiste tú u otra persona que lo mencionó en un comentario breve y rápidamente lo eliminó), muchas gracias en verdad <3
Aunque aún me sigo preguntando cómo lograr eliminar de uno en uno los espacios

Comment: Efectivamente fui yo jaja, pero me parecía que quedaba un poco apretado todo en el comentario y preferí ponerlo aquí. Ahora edito la pregunta y te enseño cómo puedes eliminar del final de un string

Comment: En verdad muchas gracias por tu ayuda <3